# print after a certain word in python

Tags: python, raw-input

In Python, I would like to read the input and then only print after a certain point. I would ***like*** for it to work like this

```
    humaninput = raw_input("Please enter:")
    breakdown = humaninput.split()
    say = "say"
    if say in breakdown:
        print (all words after say)
```

I have everything except for the last part

Comment: A small clarification is needed here. What all the answers here are suggesting is a method to split after the first occurrence of "say". If you want to change to some other occurrence of "say", you can use the `enumerate()` function to iterate through the list and modify the output as per your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you converted all the entries in to a list you can find the first instance of "say", then make a new list with everything after it.

```
humaninput = "This is me typing a whole bunch of say things with words after it"
breakdown = humaninput.split()
say = "say"
if say in breakdown:
    split = breakdown.index(say)
    after = breakdown[split+1:]
    print(after)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat alternative that doesn't use `split`.

```
string = "string blah say foo bar"
say = "say"
after = string[string.index(say) + len(say):] # +1 if you're worried about spaces
print(after)

>> foo bar
```

And if there are multiple instances of "say", it will take the first.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with `split()` if you're just using a string.

```
if say in humaninput:
  saysplit = humaninput.split(say,1)
  print saysplit[1]
```

It works on entire strings, not just single characters or nothing at all (where it defaults to space). If you've got a list, the other answer is correct.

Comment: I would set maxsplit to 1 or you will get strange output if there is more  than one "say" in the string.